# не парсится список дочерних элементов из json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
http://jsfiddle.net/Radik_Zu/racn89j1
var listCategories = [
{
    "id": "65",
    "title": "Гражданство, регистрация, визы",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "72",
            "title": "Получение паспорта",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "66",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "74",
            "title": "Регистрация по месту жительства/пребывания",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "67",
            "title": "Оформление разрешений, получение вида на жительство",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "68",
            "title": "Оформление виз, приглашений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "71",
            "title": "Вопросы гражданства",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "73",
            "title": "Предоставление статуса, переселение соотечественников в РФ",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_GRV.gif"
},
{
    "id": "226",
    "title": "Транспорт и дорожное хозяйство",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "229",
            "title": "Безопасность дорожного движения",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "232",
            "title": "ГИБДД",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "228",
            "title": "Автомототранспорт, регистрация, техосмотр",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "235",
            "title": "Лицензирование, аттестация, выдача разрешений, заключений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "234",
            "title": "Железнодорожный транспорт",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "236",
            "title": "Перевозка грузов",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "230",
            "title": "Водный транспорт",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "231",
            "title": "Авиационный транспорт, техника",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "233",
            "title": "Дорожное хозяйство",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_transport.gif"
},
{
    "id": "178",
    "title": "Социальное обеспечение ",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "184",
            "title": "Пенсионное обеспечение",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "180",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "179",
            "title": "Защита от безработицы",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "181",
            "title": "Компенсации",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "182",
            "title": "Льготы",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "185",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "186",
            "title": "Пособия",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "187",
            "title": "Признание права на льготы",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "188",
            "title": "Социальная поддержка",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "189",
            "title": "Субсидии",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_coz.gif"
},
{
    "id": "199",
    "title": "Страхование",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "202",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "205",
            "title": "Обязательное пенсионное страхование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "206",
            "title": "Обязательное медицинское страхование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "203",
            "title": "Лицензирование, регистрация, выдача разрешений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "200",
            "title": "Возмещение ущерба",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "204",
            "title": "Личное страхование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "209",
            "title": "Страхование социальное",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_strax.gif"
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Безопасность и охрана правопорядка",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "4",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "300",
            "title": "Прием заявлений и сообщений о правонарушениях",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "title": "Лицензирование, регистрация, аккредитация",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "312",
            "title": "Безопасность промышленная",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "313",
            "title": "Безопасность радиационная",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_pravooxr.gif"
},
{
    "id": "75",
    "title": "Налоги и сборы",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "79",
            "title": "Подача налоговой декларации",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "76",
            "title": "Ведение реестров, предоставление сведений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "284",
            "title": "Государственная регистрация",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_nalog.gif"
},
{
    "id": "257",
    "title": "Экономика, финансы, статистика",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "259",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "266",
            "title": "Статистика",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "258",
            "title": "Банковская деятельность",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "260",
            "title": "Лицензирование, аккредитация, выдача разрешений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "261",
            "title": "Контроль за соблюдением законодательства",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "262",
            "title": "Особые экономические зоны",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "264",
            "title": "Регулирование деятельности естественных монополий",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "267",
            "title": "Финансовые рынки",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "268",
            "title": "Ценные бумаги, акции",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "269",
            "title": "Экспорт и импорт",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "308",
            "title": "Ведение реестров, регистров, предоставление сведений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "309",
            "title": "Инвестиционная деятельность",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "315",
            "title": "Внешнеэкономическая деятельность",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_econom.gif"
},
{
    "id": "123",
    "title": "Предпринимательская деятельность",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "131",
            "title": "Лицензирование, регистрация, предоставление сведений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "124",
            "title": "Антимонопольный контроль",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "136",
            "title": "Утверждение заключений, согласование",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_predprinimat.gif"
},
{
    "id": "220",
    "title": "Информационные технологии и связь",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "221",
            "title": "Лицензирование, аккредитация, предоставление информации",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "288",
            "title": "Информатизация",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "287",
            "title": "Связь",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "223",
            "title": "Почтовые услуги",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "224",
            "title": "Телекоммуникации",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "222",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "225",
            "title": "ЭВМ",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "310",
            "title": "Контроль и надзор",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_telecom.gif"
},
{
    "id": "42",
    "title": "Земельно-имущественные отношения",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "48",
            "title": "Недвижимость",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "45",
            "title": "Земельные отношения",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "46",
            "title": "Информирование, получение сведений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "49",
            "title": "Недра",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "47",
            "title": "Выдача разрешений, лицензирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "290",
            "title": "Государственное имущество",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_zeml.gif"
},
{
    "id": "29",
    "title": "Здравоохранение и медицина",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "31",
            "title": "Высокотехнологичная медицинская помощь",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "35",
            "title": "Медико-социальная экспертиза",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "30",
            "title": "Лицензирование, сертификация, выдача заключений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "41",
            "title": "Фармацевтическая деятельность",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "32",
            "title": "Изделия медицинского назначения",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "40",
            "title": "Медицинская техника",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "305",
            "title": "Ведение реестров, регистров, предоставление сведений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "38",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "39",
            "title": "Потеря трудоспособности",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "296",
            "title": "Медицинская помощь",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_zdrav.gif"
},
{
    "id": "82",
    "title": "Некоммерческие организации",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "84",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "85",
            "title": "Лицензирование, аккредитация и регистрация",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "86",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_nekom.gif"
},
{
    "id": "101",
    "title": "Государственные учреждения",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "107",
            "title": "Прием населения",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "102",
            "title": "Государственные услуги",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "103",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "105",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "106",
            "title": "Получение выписок из архивов, информации, справок",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "293",
            "title": "Делопроизводство",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_gosuchrejdeniya.gif"
},
{
    "id": "149",
    "title": "Реклама и СМИ ",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "153",
            "title": "Регистрация, лицензирование, выдача разрешений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "151",
            "title": "Издательская деятельность",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "289",
            "title": "Получение льгот, поддержки",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "152",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "150",
            "title": "Антимонопольный контроль",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_smi.gif"
},
{
    "id": "108",
    "title": "Природопользование и экология",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "117",
            "title": "Охрана окружающей среды",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "110",
            "title": "Выдача разрешений, заключений и квот",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "115",
            "title": "Недра",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "109",
            "title": "Водные ресурсы",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "111",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "112",
            "title": "Земельные угодья",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "113",
            "title": "Лесные ресурсы",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "114",
            "title": "Лицензирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "120",
            "title": "Рыболовство",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "121",
            "title": "Предоставление территорий, акваторий, воздушного пространства",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "122",
            "title": "Экспертизы",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_priroda.gif"
},
{
    "id": "160",
    "title": "Сельское хозяйство и ветеринария",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "161",
            "title": "Ветеринария",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "164",
            "title": "Лицензирование, регистрация, выдача разрешений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "162",
            "title": "Животноводство",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "163",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "166",
            "title": "Растениеводство",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "167",
            "title": "Сельское хозяйство",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "302",
            "title": "Производство кормов, лекарственных средств для животных",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "303",
            "title": "Проведение экспертиз, выдача заключений",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_selhoz.gif"
},
{
    "id": "276",
    "title": "Юридические услуги",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "281",
            "title": "Патентное право",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "277",
            "title": "Адвокатские услуги",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "278",
            "title": "Легализация документов",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "280",
            "title": "Нотариальные услуги",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "297",
            "title": "Регистрация актов гражданского состояния",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_yur.gif"
},
{
    "id": "51",
    "title": "Культура, искусство",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "53",
            "title": "Библиотечное дело",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "54",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "52",
            "title": "Архивное дело",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "55",
            "title": "Историко-культурные территории",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "56",
            "title": "Аттестация, лицензирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "57",
            "title": "Культурные ценности, объекты культурного наследия",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "59",
            "title": "Учреждения культуры",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "301",
            "title": "Проведение экспертиз, выдача заключений",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_cultura.gif"
},
{
    "id": "138",
    "title": "Производство, строительство и торговля",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "139",
            "title": "Лицензирование, регистрация, выдача разрешений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "147",
            "title": "Строительство",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "145",
            "title": "Проведение экспертизы, выдача заключений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "146",
            "title": "Промышленность",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "148",
            "title": "Торговля",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "294",
            "title": "Ведение реестров, предоставление сведений",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_proizvodstvo.gif"
},
{
    "id": "210",
    "title": "Таможенное дело",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "211",
            "title": "Ввоз и вывоз товаров и грузов",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "218",
            "title": "Таможенное оформление",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "212",
            "title": "Лицензирование, регистрация",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "215",
            "title": "Транзит",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "216",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "217",
            "title": "Таможенная служба",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_tamognya.gif"
},
{
    "id": "88",
    "title": "Образование и наука",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "89",
            "title": "Высшее образование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "92",
            "title": "Лицензирование, аккредитация и аттестация",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "91",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "93",
            "title": "Наука и инновации",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "94",
            "title": "Научная деятельность",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "95",
            "title": "Ученые степени",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "98",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_obrazovanie.gif"
},
{
    "id": "13",
    "title": "Жилищно-коммунальное хозяйство",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "16",
            "title": "Лицензирование, аттестация",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_gkx.gif"
},
{
    "id": "7",
    "title": "Картография, геодезия и гидрометеорология",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "8",
            "title": "Аккредитация и лицензирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "title": "Геодезические и картографические работы",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "291",
            "title": "Гидрометеорология",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_cart.gif"
},
{
    "id": "21",
    "title": "Защита прав и свобод",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "22",
            "title": "Защита прав",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "23",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "25",
            "title": "Охрана жизни",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "28",
            "title": "Проведение экспертиз, выдача заключений",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_zashita.gif"
},
{
    "id": "60",
    "title": "Международная деятельность",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "61",
            "title": "Информирование",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_international.png"
},
{
    "id": "169",
    "title": "Семья",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "177",
            "title": "Усыновление и опека",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_senya.gif"
},
{
    "id": "238",
    "title": "Труд и занятость",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "239",
            "title": "Защита от безработицы",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "240",
            "title": "Иностранные работники",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "241",
            "title": "Лицензирование, регистрация, предоставление сведений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "243",
            "title": "Повышение квалификации",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "247",
            "title": "Трудоустройство",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "248",
            "title": "Урегулирование трудовых споров",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_trud.gif"
},
{
    "id": "270",
    "title": "Энергетика и природные ресурсы",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "271",
            "title": "Лицензирование, выдача разрешений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "273",
            "title": "Подача обращений, жалоб и предложений",
            "children": []
        },
        {
            "id": "274",
            "title": "Управление государственным имуществом",
            "children": []
        }
    ],
    "ico": "ico_cat_energia.gif"
}
```

];

```
    var list = '';
    function parseCatRecursive(item){
        for(var key in item){
            if(key === 'title')
                list += '<li class="lw" id="'+ key +'">' + item[key] + '</li>';
            if(key === 'children' && item[key].length !== 0){
                list += '<li><ul>';
                parseCatRecursive(item[key]);
                list += '</ul></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    listCategories.forEach(function(item){
        list += '<ul>';
        parseCatRecursive(item);
        list += '</ul>';
    });

    $('body').html(list);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дочерние элементы не выводятся потому что, вы передаете в функцию массив объектов, а функция ждет ассоциативный массив.

Код нужно изменить примерно так:

```
    var list = '';
    function parseCatRecursive(cat){
        cat.forEach(function(item){
            list += '<ul>';
            for(var key in item){
                if(key === 'title')
                    list += '<li class="lw" id="'+ key +'">' + item[key] + '</li>';
                if(key === 'children' && item[key].length !== 0){
                    list += '<ul>';
                    parseCatRecursive(item[key]);
                    list += '</ul>';
                }
            }
            list += '</ul>';
        });
    }
    parseCatRecursive(listCategories);

    $('body').html(list);
```

Пример работы http://jsfiddle.net/9zmwurt3/ (В примере к последнему элементу добавил еще потомка 2 уровня для наглядности).